# Using Ajax with JQuery .on()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to combine these two functions but my knowledge of Ajax and JS isn't that strong yet and I don't know how i would go about doing it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_item', function() {
    var indx = $(this).index();
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'NavBar.php',
    data: {'indx': pat_id},
});
```

basically I want to send the JS variable `indx` to the php variable `pat_id`.

When the user clicks on the `li` it would be received as something like this.

```
<li class= "list_item" onclick ="<?php $pat_id = $_POST ['indx']; ?>">
```

this would all be happening inside the same php file: NavBar.php.

Comment: Put the ajax call inside the click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.list_item', function() {
        var indx = $(this).index();
        $.ajax({ // add ajax code here
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'NavBar.php',
        data: {pat_id: indx}, // send parameter like this
        success: function(response) {
               console.log(response);
        }
        });
    });
```

So in NavBar.php you can access pat_id like this:

```
echo $_POST['pat_id'];
```

Comment: Just to clarify in the it would look something like this <li onclick = echo $_POST ['pat_id']> and the variable pat_id would have the value of the JS variable? or would I have to write the POST command outside of the li?

Comment: $_POST['pat_id'] will contain the indx js variable's value, and yes you can use it in li using $_POST['pat_id']....

Comment: it's giving me an error saying that pat_id is not defined but the console reacts with XHR finished loading POST followed by errors similar to: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'shiprequest_NavBar.php' not found...I don't see why there's a pathing issue when I am sending the post to the same url containing the code